# How to add a "column" back to txt file after creating the column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strip

So I have a .LAS file (it works practically as txt file) and I converted it to a dataframe. Later I created a new column with some important information on the dataframe. 
Is there a way to rewrite the LAS file similar to the original one, but now with the new column?

Here is how my LAS file was:

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
~A Stats1 Stats2 Stats3
     1       2     3
     6       6     7
     8       9     3
```

So I managed to convert the file to a DataFrame the way I wanted (without the header and '~A'):

```
with open(r'C:...filename.las') as f:
    for l in f:
        if l.startswith('~A'):
            stats= l.split()[1:]
            break
    data = pd.read_csv(f, names=stats, sep='~A', engine='python')

data

Stats1 Stats2 Stats3 Numbers
  1       2      3      1
  6       6      7      2
  8       9      3      3
```

Now, imagine that I created a new column data['Numbers'] with numbers(1,2,3) and if I managed to rewrite this back to my LAS file, it should be like:

````
```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
~A Stats1 Stats2 Stats3 Numbers
     1       2     3       1
     6       6     7       2
     8       9     3       3
```
````

Anyone knows how can I do that?

if I just use:
    
`np.savetxt('filename_edited.las', data, fmt="%s")`

...I manage to get the new LAS file with the data I wanted, but without the header I had on the original file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the header when reading the file, so you can write it back. Otherwise it's lost.

To write the dataframe, you can use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) after you have written back the header text.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    file_header = []
    for l in f:
        if l.startswith('~A'):
            stats= l.split()[1:]
            break
        else:
            file_header.append(l)

    data = pd.read_csv(f, names=stats, sep='\s+', engine='python')

#manipulate the dataframe to add a column or whatever
data['numbers'] = [1, 2, 3]

with open('data2.txt', 'w') as wf:
    data_str = data.to_csv(None)
    for l in file_header:
        wf.write(l)
    wf.write('~A')
    wf.write(data_str)
```

And *data2.txt* will look like:

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
~A,Stats1,Stats2,Stats3,numbers
0,1,2,3,1
1,6,6,7,2
2,8,9,3,3
```

`to_csv` use a comma separator by default, but you can use the `sep` argument to specify a different one. Must be a string of length 1.

Comment: If I just put ...data.to_csv(None, sep='\t', index=False)...it stays the way I need. Thanks a lot, @Valentino.